# How can I configure an UltraWide monitor next to a 4K monitor using Xrandr

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, hdpi

I have a desktop PC with Ubuntu and would like to know the correct Xrandr command to correctly use one 4K (3840x2160 DP-0) monitor next to a UltraWide (2560x1080 HDMI-0) monitor with the a correct scale (maybe 1.5x1.5).

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and have tried with the suggestions on Arch Linux Wiki but I can't find a right command for my case. Everything mess up each time.

[image: Diagram of the monitors]

Comment: Are you using wayland or xorg? What commands did you run and what is the output?

Comment: Xorg. It is a default Ubuntu 18.04 installation. I used lots of commands. The near to work one at this point is: `xrandr --output DP-0 --auto --output HDMI-0 --auto --panning 5120x2160+3840+0 --scale 1.1x1.1 --right-of DP-0` but it just don't work, it creates a mess that I can't describe but less mess that other commands that I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 with Xorg here too.

I am also looking for the solution to a similar problem. I have managed to get it to work for a layout where the ultrawide screen is either above or below the 4K one, but not when they are sitting side by side.

These are the commands required in order to get it to work in an above/below fashion:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1x1 --pos 960x2160
xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 2x2 --mode 2560x1080 --fb 5120x3960 --pos 0x0
```

The first one sets the position to be below the ultrawide - and centred. The position should be set using the real dimensions \times the scale being used (`2.0` in this example), hence the `960x2160`.

The second command sets the scale of the ultrawide to `2.0 x 2.0`, and sets the required framebuffer size, which I believe to be `max(3200, 2560*2) x (1800 + 1080*2)` - hence, `5120x3960` - for an above/below layout.

[image]

I have tried to use a similar logic for the side-by-side layout but without success...

These are the commands I tried:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 2x2 --mode 2560x1080 --fb 8320x2160 --pos 3200x0
```

And this is the result...

[image]

Ps. I am commenting as an "answer" because I wanted to be able to post the picture above.

Comment: I noticed I got that weird pattern from your picture when I had a configuration for fakexrandr.  Clearing the configuration and restarting got me back to a clean picture.